# macBook is running at 1000% CPU

Tags: mac, performance, cpu

I have a 2019 MacBook  that is running kerneld at 1000% CPU (yes 1000%) no matter if I boot the OS or even into Recovery Mode. However, when I boot into Recovery Mode with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> I can also hear the fan running full speed, and the system is very non-responsive. This makes me think it isn't an OS issue, it is something about the firmware boot.

I erased the NVRAM with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> and still no change.

I booted into Target Disk Mode by holding down <kbd>T</kbd> so I can copy some files off it before a complete reinstall, but even that is running the fan hot and the machine never shows up as a disk on the other laptop.

Update: I also note that even with the device completely shut down it will not charge the battery.

I am at a loss as to next steps short of return to base. Any ideas?

Comment: @Allen - the post has a number of options. All of which I don't think is correct because one issue is that the device will not charge at all. But I just got off a call with Apple Support. The problem certainly appears to be hardware and I am taking it in to Apple this week. I will update this post when I get some details from Apple.